# Transit visa at Moscow

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, moscow

I am an Indian citizen. I want to travel from New Delhi to Geneva via Moscow by Aeroflot with 3 hrs 30 mts layover at Moscow. Do I need a transit visa.

Comment: Presumably, you're traveling with Aeroflot (SU) via Sheremetyevo (SVO). In this case, for layovers shorter than 24h, if your route is on a single booking, you may remain in the international transit area (even if changing terminals), and no visa is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic transiting without a visa is possible for passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

TWOV does not apply to passengers departing to Sevastopol (UKS) or Simferopol (SIP).

TWOV does not apply at Irkutsk (IKT), Kaliningrad (KGD), Khabarovsk (KHV), Krasnodar (KRR), Mineralnye Vody (MRV), Rostov-on-Don (ROV), Sochi (AER), Yuzhno Sakhalinsk (UUS) and Zhukovsky (ZIA).

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b